# ¿Cómo ordenar una consulta sql usando una variable dinámica? MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysqldb

Pongo este código para dar una idea de lo que quiero hacer, no funciona ya que son string, pero **¿Cómo podría hacer para que funcionara o necesariamente debo hacerlo desde código?**

```
SET @columna = 'apePaterno';
SET @ordenar = 'asc';
SELECT apePaterno, apeMaterno, nombres, edad FROM personas ORDER BY @columna @ordenar;
```

Comment: Usando case se podría hacer algo, pero le veo poco sentido, creo que es más práctico hacerlo por código.

Comment: @juan podrías darme un ejemplo con el case? si se puede con mysql quisiera hacerlo con mysql

Comment: Sería una medio solución no vale para el orden, y sinceramente me parece poco eficaz, pero bueno: 
SELECT * FROM personas ORDER BY 
 case
  when (@columna="apePaterno" ) then apePaterno
  when (@columna="apeMaterno") then apeMaterno
 end
Si te sirve de idea base. Insisto que yo usaría un procedimeinto para hacer esto., directamente no lo veo.